# Multicollinearity and Partial Dependence Questions

Tags: machine-learning, interpretation, multicollinearity, partial-effect

Assume I build a binary classification model to predict p(y=1) from {x1, x2, ... x10}

For now, assume that model could be a GBM, RandomForest, or Logistic Regression.

Also assume that all of the independent variables are independent from one another, with the exception that **x2 and x3 are strongly positively correlated with each other**.

After the model is built, I run **Partial Dependence Plots** to try and gain some understanding on the variables and the model outcome.

What I've observed is this: *the line on the PDP chart for x2 and x3 are going in opposite directions*. If I train a new model without using x3, then the PDP line for x2 is increasing. If I train a new model without using x3, then the PDP line for x2 is also increasing. However, when I train a model using both x2 and x3, then the PDP line for x2 is increasing, while the line for x3 is decreasing.

1. Is this "normal" when 2 variables are strongly correlated with each other?
2. Does this depend on the underlying model as having an assumption of independence like Logistic Regression? Or can I assume that this effect can happen using algorithms like RandomForest and GBM as well?

I feel like the assumptions behind partial dependence are what is creating this problem - and not the underlying model itself.

3. If the answers to #1 is "yes", and the answer to #2 is that the underlying algorithm won't matter... Then are there other options to understand the effects (other than just excluding one of the variables).